FFMpeg: How to get the real return value in bash
I've always used ffmpeg via a cmd-script and I always could check the %ERRORLEVEL% which was always '0' on success or '!0' if an error occured.
I'm trying to recode my cmd-scripts in bash (using msys2 for windows), like bash gives me much more control over the scripting (I experienced, bash is a 1000 times better than cmd). But when I do someting like this
status=$($ffMpegPath -hide_banner -y "${aInput[@]}" "${aMapping[@]}" -c copy "${aParam[@]}" "$destination")

then $status always is '0' (success), even if an error in ffmpeg occures.
What am I missing?
Am I doing something wrong?
I'm coding bash in msys2 for windows, in windows11. $ffMpegPath is a global variable that points to the unix-path where my ffmpeg is located, it's been declared as a global like following :
declare -r ffMpegPath="/c/Tools/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"

[Appendum]
To clarrify some things, following is the command (without '-hide_banner') :
/c/Tools/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -y -i /f/Kigo/Film/raw/input.mp4 -i /f/Kigo/Film/Audio/input.French.mp4 -map 0:V -map 0:a -map 1:a -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 -sn -dn -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 language=und -disposition:v:0 default -metadata:s:v:0 title= -metadata:s:a:0 title= -metadata:s:a:1 title= -metadata:s:v:0 SOURCE_ID-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 SOURCE_ID-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 SOURCE_ID-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 BPS= -metadata:s:a:0 BPS= -metadata:s:a:1 BPS= -metadata:s:v:0 BPS-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 BPS-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 BPS-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 DURATION= -metadata:s:a:0 DURATION= -metadata:s:a:1 DURATION= -metadata:s:v:0 DURATION-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 DURATION-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 DURATION-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES= -metadata:s:a:0 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES= -metadata:s:a:1 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES= -metadata:s:v:0 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 NUMBER_OF_BYTES= -metadata:s:a:0 NUMBER_OF_BYTES= -metadata:s:a:1 NUMBER_OF_BYTES= -metadata:s:v:0 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP= -metadata:s:a:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP= -metadata:s:a:1 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP= -metadata:s:v:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC= -metadata:s:a:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC= -metadata:s:a:1 _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC= -metadata:s:v:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 _STATISTICS_TAGS= -metadata:s:a:0 _STATISTICS_TAGS= -metadata:s:a:1 _STATISTICS_TAGS= -metadata:s:v:0 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng= -metadata:s:a:0 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng= -metadata:s:a:1 _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng= -metadata:s:v:0 HANDLER_NAME= -metadata:s:a:0 HANDLER_NAME= -metadata:s:a:1 HANDLER_NAME= -metadata:s:v:0 VENDOR_ID= -metadata:s:a:0 VENDOR_ID= -metadata:s:a:1 VENDOR_ID= -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=fra /e/Video/MP4/output.mp4

and following is its (truncated) output :
ffmpeg version N-114362-gbc9e6bd678-gac21582e53+3 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration:  --pkg-config=pkgconf --cc='ccache gcc' --cxx='ccache g++' --ld='ccache g++' --extra-cxxflags=-fpermissive --extra-cflags=-Wno-int-conversion --disable-autodetect --enable-amf --enable-bzlib --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-iconv --enable-lzma --enable-nvenc --enable-zlib --enable-sdl2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libaom --disable-debug --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-fontconfig --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmfx --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libshine --enable-gpl --enable-avisynth --enable-libxvid --enable-libopenmpt --enable-version3 --enable-librav1e --enable-libsrt --enable-libgsm --enable-libvmaf --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-chromaprint --enable-decklink --enable-frei0r --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libilbc --enable-libsvthevc --enable-libsvtvp9 --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmodplug --enable-librist --enable-librtmp --enable-librubberband --enable-libtesseract --enable-libxavs --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-libcodec2 --enable-ladspa --enable-libglslang --enable-vulkan --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libplacebo --enable-libjxl --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenh264 --enable-openssl --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-libs=-lstdc++ --extra-cflags=-DCACA_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DMODPLUG_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DCHROMAPRINT_NODLL --extra-libs=-lstdc++ --extra-cflags=-DZMQ_STATIC --extra-libs=-lpsapi --extra-cflags=-DLIBXML_STATIC --extra-libs=-liconv --disable-w32threads --extra-cflags=-DKVZ_STATIC_LIB --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-DAL_LIBTYPE_STATIC --extra-cflags='-IC:/mab/local64/include' --extra-cflags='-IC:/mab/local64/include/AL'
  libavutil      59.  6.100 / 59.  6.100
  libavcodec     61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavformat    61.  0.100 / 61.  0.100
  libavdevice    61.  0.100 / 61.  0.100
  libavfilter    10.  0.100 / 10.  0.100
  libswscale      8.  0.100 /  8.  0.100
  libswresample   5.  0.100 /  5.  0.100
  libpostproc    58.  0.100 / 58.  0.100


Does Detecting program errors in bash scripts? answer your question?

not chatching the status code, but instead testing '$?' right after the command, gives me the same effect. Always returns '0', even if ffmpeg has errors (the red text after which ffmpeg terminates)

The error-code returned by ffmpeg is not guaranteed to be non-zero in case
of error.
One solution is to use the -xerror parameter, which stands for
"Stop and exit on error". The return error-code is said to be more
reliable with this parameter, and the code of 0 indicates that
there has been no error.
Another solution is to use the parameter -v error and redirect
the output with the errors into a text file that can be searched,
and test the error-code returned by the search-tool.
References :

ffmpeg Documentation
How to tell if ffmpeg errored or not?


if ffmpeg encounters some or more errors, it gives a red error-message and then exits the task. But still '$?' or in my case by catching the return value in a variable, gives me '0'. Using '-v error' is not actually what I want. Because with the ret-value the script does some tasks if successfull, or something else (like terminating the script) when it fails.

btw, I did try the '-xerror' option, added a faulty option '-nope', ffmpeg didn't recognise the option (of course) and exited, but still its return value seems to be '0' ??

This might be worth a bug-report in the ffmpeg forums. The error-code returned by ffmpeg seems not to be very consistent.

Okay, I did some more testing, and seems in bash 'status=$(ffmpeg....)' always sets the return value to '0', even if -xerror has been added with ffmpeg. But if first call ffmpeg (with -xerror) and after that command line set 'status=$?' then it sets the status to not-0. So for me it seems to be solved. Still wondering why 'status=$(ffmpeg...)' doesn't work, it does with other external commands I call this way. Anyway, for now it's solved. Tx.

Well, a few days later I learned a lot about BASH.
It seems I was missing a lot.
When I do
result=$(ffmpeg <options>...)

then I won't get its return value, but whatever it would report to screen, like you get when you use ffprobe. Properly you won't get anything from ffmpeg, I'm not sure about that.
But where I was wrong, I have to add right after the ffmpeg-command, something like this :
retvalue=$?

in order to get the return-value of the command (like ERRORLEVEL in a windows-cmd environment).
So I'm sorry to bother, my mistake.
